# 'imagick' Module already loaded every time I run php

Tags: php, error-handling, ini

I am having an issue on my server where every time I run a php command I am getting in my error logs `PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`

I understand that this is because somewhere the module is being loaded more than once.

So I did some poking around and discovered I have three `.ini` files loading the same module with `extenstion=imagick.so`.

```
imagick.ini
zzzzzzz-pecl.ini
zzzzzzz-pecl.ini.rpmsave
```

All if these `.ini` are located in my `php.d`

The issue I am having is where I can fix this issue. I know that pecl has to do with imagick but I am not sure where I can fix this so it loads once.

Answer (score 1):

check all other .ini files and delete the lines "extension=imagick.so" in every .ini files except imagick.ini.

then restart apache.